# get iframe by its title with javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to get the iframe by it's title. The iframe doesn't have a name, id or a class. I want to get the Iframe just by it's title with plain javascript.

This is the iframe :

```
<iframe title="iframetitle" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Please don't use Jquery or any plugin!

Comment: `document.querySelector('iframe[title=iframetitle]')`?

Comment: querySelector takes a CSS selector so here is more info on CSS selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find the iframe. A value inside of brackets searches for attributes `[name]`, `[title]`, `[data-descr]`, etc. When adding an `=` something, you then are also searching the value, so `[title=iframetitle]` would look for something that has a `title` **attribute** with a **value** of `iframetitle`.

We could enhance the query more by saying it also has to be an `iframe` by doing `iframe[title=iframetitle]`.

Here is a working example:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('iframe[title=iframetitle]'))
```

```html
<iframe title="iframetitle" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```